# Dot Game and Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I'm trying to solve a variant of the dot game with dynamic programming.

The regular dot game is played with a line of dots. Each player takes either one or two dots at their respective end of the line and the person who is left with no dots to take wins.

In this version of the game, each dot has a different value. Each player takes alternate turns and takes either dot at either end of the line. I want to come up with a way to use dynamic programming to find the max amount that the first player is guaranteed to win.

I'm having problems grasping my head around this and trying to write a recurrence for the solution. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the goal of your version of the game? To maximize the number of points picked up? Or maybe to maximize the difference between your points and the opponent's points?

Comment: @Gabe: since, as far as I understand, the total number of points is fixed, those two options you talk about are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this site: http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/, especially problem number 10:

> Optimal Strategy for a Game. Consider a row of n coins of values v(1) ... v(n), where n is even. We play a game against an opponent by alternating turns. In each turn, a player selects either the first or last coin from the row, removes it from the row permanently, and receives the value of the coin. Determine the maximum possible amount of money we can definitely win if we move first.

It's exactly what you want if I'm reading your post right. The solution is pretty simple and it's explained very well there in my opinion.

Comment: Oh my god, this site is excellent! I'm training for programming competitions but im very newbie and im trying to grasp all the techniques ( Backtracking, Graph algorithms, ... ), i'm learning dynamic programming and this site will be of great help!

I am having difficulties with recurrence relations ( i can understand the answers but it's very hard for me to develop one alone). Do you know any resource like this for them?

Comment: @Alessandro Stamatto - there's the topcoder DP tutorial that's very good: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static - and also the wikipedia entry on dynamic programming, which you've probably seen. Other than that I don't know any others. Most pages talk about one or two particular problems, so if you get stuck on something, you should just search for that problem. Eventually you'll get the hang of it.